# How do I return the x_values and loss values at each iteration of a pytorch optimiser?

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am writing a simple optimisation procedure for finding the square root of a number. I have written this using pytorches LBFGS algorithm from torch.optim. For the write-up I need the value of the loss function and the x-value given at each iteration of this optimiser, with max_iter = 5 this should return 5 sets of numbers. This is *not* a machine learning program so I don't have any epochs or training function or anything like that.

I've been told to look at lightning callback functions which look like they can do the job but I can't work out how to implement this. All I need is to see a working example of this which I can't seem to find.

Here is the code for the optimisation so far:

```
x0 = torch.rand(1,dtype=torch.float64,requires_grad=True)
y = torch.sqrt(x0)

loss_fn = lambda z: torch.abs(y-z)

opt = torch.optim.LBFGS([x0],max_iter = 5)

def closure():
        opt.zero_grad()
        objective = loss_fn(x0)
        objective.backward(retain_graph=True)
        return objective

x1 = opt.step(closure)
```